# How to extract photos from email?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, photo

I have a need to poll a mail server and then extract a photo that is either embedded or attached to the email message.

The goal is to extract the photo and save it to a disk file. The desired functionality is much like emailing a photo from your phone to Twitter, Flickr, etc.

Any insights/advice appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have not tried anything yet. Researching before I start to make the most efficient use of my time.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this in the past: [Dart Power TCP](http://www.dart.com/purchase.aspx?pl=PowerTCP). It is NOT a free product but it works well. I was able to check and parse POP email messages without too much trouble. I think you could grab email attachments and/or get image URLs out of HTML emails with this tool.