# How to upload or send photo from iOS device to web server

Tags: asp.net, ios, iphone-web-app

How can I allow a user from an iOS device to upload an image to my server using asp.net?

**NOTE** A native iOS application is not an option for us at this time.

I'm open to any crazy idea, like emailing the image to some email address that I monitor which in turn puts it into a database that the web application is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending via email is common practice as far as I know.

Comment: Do you know of a good method to pick up and parse the email? Any library or something?

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256568/how-to-extract-photos-from-email